# FATAL EXCEPTION in Android When getting Double Varible Values

Tags: android, android-studio, exception, double, numberformatexception

I'm using a button to calculate discounts when the user input the discount rate to the app. When I get a Total Value below 1000 it is working fine and gives the discount. But if the total value is greater than 1000, it gives the Fatal Exception and crashes the app. Can you help me to fix this issue?
Thank you

```
 calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Double discountRate = Double.parseDouble(input_rate.getText().toString());
                Double  discount = 0.0;

                if(discountRate.equals("")){
                    Toast.makeText(CreateInvoiceActivity.this, "Discount Rate is Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {
                    Double totalValue = Double.parseDouble(invoiceTotal.getText().toString());
                    
                    try {
                        discount = (totalValue * (discountRate / 100));
                        
                        Toast.makeText(CreateInvoiceActivity.this, "Discount is" + discount, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }catch (NumberFormatException ignore){}
                }
            }
        });
```

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.antlergroup.aits.ierunt.ai, PID: 26795
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1,008.00"
        at java.lang.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1306)
        at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:547)
        at com.antlergroup.aits.ierunt.ai.view.activity.CreateInvoiceActivity$2.onClick(CreateInvoiceActivity.java:291)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5647)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22479)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:761)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6623)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 26795 SIG: 9
```

Comment: It is the thousands separator (comma `,` here). Use Locale specifiable `MessageFormat.parse`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the thousands separator (comma).

```
Double totalValue = Double.parseDouble(invoiceTotal.getText().toString().replace(",", ""));
```

You should also:

- Prefer [java.text.NumberFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) to parse the number
- Use the correct locale
- Validate the input

Comment: Thank you so much